# Saving data on postback in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I'm an Orchard newbie and I'm having difficulty trying to get the form data when a new item is created.

What I have is a module that creates a menu item on the admin dashboard.  That menu item will load a page where a user can enter a new "Coach".

There are 3 things needed for a coach, first name, last name and email.

Here's the code I have implemented for this...

migrations.cs

```
public class SDSDataMigration : DataMigrationImpl
{

    public int Create()
    {
        SchemaBuilder..CreateTable("CoachPartRecord", table => table.ContentPartRecord()
.Column("FirstName", DbType.AnsiString, c => c.WithLength(50))                                                                                   
.Column("LastName", DbType.AnsiString, c => c.WithLength(50))                                                                         
.Column("Email", DbType.AnsiString, c => c.WithLength(200)))

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("CoachPart", part => part
                                                                          .WithField("FirstName", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
                                                                          .WithField("LastName", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
                                                                          .WithField("Email", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
                                                                          );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Coach", type => type.WithPart("CommonPart")
                                                                          .WithPart("CoachPart"));

        return 1;
    }

}
```

parts/records

```
public class CoachPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}

public class CoachPart : ContentPart<CoachPartRecord>
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return Record.FirstName; }
        set { Record.FirstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return Record.LastName; }
        set { Record.LastName = value; }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return Record.Email; }
        set { Record.Email = value; }
    }        
}
```

view for creating editor

```
@{ Layout.Title = T("Add Coach").ToString(); }
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) {
// Model is a Shape, calling Display() so that it is rendered using the most specific template for its Shape type
@Display(Model)
}
```

handler

```
public class CoachPartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public CoachPartHandler(IRepository<CoachPartRecord> repository)
    {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }
}
```

driver

```
protected override DriverResult Editor(CoachPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
```

controller (for dashboard menu item)

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var coach = _services.ContentManager.New("Coach");
        var model = _services.ContentManager.BuildEditor(coach);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult CreatePOST()
    {
        var contentItem = _services.ContentManager.New("Coach");
        _services.ContentManager.Publish(contentItem);

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Right now I can get the form to appear to create a new coach.  When I hit "Publish" all of the fields (i.e. FirstName, LastName, Email) for the CoachPart parameter in the driver are null.

I can look at the http request and I can see the values I put on the form, but they're not making it to the CoachPart.

Any ideas why the CoachPart fields aren't getting filed in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are defining the properties on your own record. Therefore you don't need new textfields attached to your part, so you should remove this:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("CoachPart", part => part
    .WithField("FirstName", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
    .WithField("LastName", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
    .WithField("Email", f => f.OfType("TextField")));
```

Secondly, because you use your custom controller istead of orchard's content controller, you must implement the `IUpdateModel` and act on it:

```
[Admin]
public class MyController : Controller, IUpdateModel {
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
    private readonly ITransactionManager _transactionManager;

    public MyController(IContentManager contentManager,
        ITransactionManager transactionManager) {

        _contentManager = contentManager;
        _transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult CreatePOST()
    {
        var contentItem = _contentManager.New<CoachPart>("Coach");

        // The implementation of IUpdateModel is necessary for this next line:
        var model = _contentManager.UpdateEditor(contentItem, this);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            _transactionManager.Cancel();
            return View(model);
        }

        _contentManager.Publish(contentItem);

        return View("Index");
    }

    bool IUpdateModel.TryUpdateModel<TModel>(TModel model, string prefix, string[] includeProperties, string[] excludeProperties) {
        return TryUpdateModel(model, prefix, includeProperties, excludeProperties);
    }

    void IUpdateModel.AddModelError(string key, LocalizedString errorMessage) {
        ModelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!   That was it.  I did have to implement an editor template.  I also had to change the code...

_contentManager.Publish(contentItem);

to

_contentManager.Publish(contentItem.ContentItem);

but it started saving after that.  I've been chasing that for a few days.  Thanks!